# Do I need to create new APNS key if I change my distribution certificate?

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications, apple-developer

My distribution certificate is expired and I am creating new certificate and profile. After creating new certificate and profile do I need tom create new APNS key ans save it on my app server?

Comment: No there is no link between distribution certificates and APNS keys